# Hide drop-down box on basis of text result using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to hide a drop-down on the basis of a selected user input.

So far I have done

```
var getText = document.getElementById('issuemeters-issuance_type').value;
```

Then in if else condition

```
if(getText == 'HESCO/OEM')
         {
                $('.field-issuemeters-issuer').hide();// the drop-down which i want to hide
                $('#issuemeters-issuer').val('');// setting the text value to null
         }
         else 
         {
                $('.field-issuemeters-issuer').show();     
         }
```

It will work when `getText` is equal to `HESCO/OEM`. I have also checked the value in `console` but I don't know why it's not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide us some "live" code example (maybe in JSFiddle) that we could see the problem?

Comment: Did you read the value of the input field _after_ it was changed/input ...?

Comment: you have to add `change` event listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with a listener on "issuemeters-issuance_type" change:

```
$('#issuemeters-issuance_type').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).val() === 'HESCO/OEM')
         {
                $('.field-issuemeters-issuer').hide();// the drop-down which i want to hide
                $('#issuemeters-issuer').val('');// setting the text value to null
         }
         else 
         {
                $('.field-issuemeters-issuer').show();     
         }
});
```

assuming that "issuemeters-issuance_type"